# Descriptive statistics for ranked choice data frame

Tags: r

I have been hustling with an issue that should be easy to figure out and need help.
There are four ranked choice variables V1, V2, V3, V4 in my *dataset dtst*.

```
    <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1      1    3      1      2   
2      3    5      4      1   
3      2    1      2      5  
4      5    3      3      3   
5      4    2      5      4
```

I need to summarize what is the second most popular choice per each variable.
I have mostly been trying to use the package "pmr" to do it.

```
rankings<-data.frame(dtst[, 1:4])
rankings_agg<-rankagg(rankings)
```

After I try running the next *destat* command, it prints an error.

```
rankings_st<-destat(rankings_agg)
```

I am not sure it is even the way to go for my task. I need to build some table with pairwise comparisons basically.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  slice(2) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = "Variable", 
    values_to = "Top_2"
  )
```

```
  Variable Top_2
  <chr>    <int>
1 V1           3
2 V2           5
3 V3           4
4 V4           1
```

Comment: Nice solution. Still, the variables in provided data do not have enough rows to determine which category is second most popular. Most of them are emptied. Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much, TarJae. This work for me. Is there a way to add percentages to Top 2?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: 1 =  80% to 100% and 5 is 0% to 20%, ...?